# Remove 'Embed watch content' on the basis of a scheme

Tags: ios, xcode, watchos

We are creating a companion watch app for our mobile applications. We have created two different mobile apps from a single codebase and a single target by using different schemes.

But we want to release watch only for one of the mobile apps.

So is there a way to remove 'Embed watch content' on the basis of the scheme or some script/pre-action that can be executed while compilation per the scheme for removing watch content?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question, I believe there is no way to separate out this on the basis of the scheme. Schemes are associated with a target.

I created a separate target and made it mobile app only. Applied the corresponding theme on them.

Separate target gives you the capability to modify build settings as per need.